# How to merge a partition to my main file system

Tags: partitioning, gparted, merge

This is my gparted window:

[image: Screenshot of the window]

How can I add Partition-2 (the selected row) to my main file system?

Comment: Generally; that partition table is a mess, the easy way to get rid of such mess is to take backup and then clean out the disk entirely, then reinstall the one OS you wish to use.

Comment: Little key icon shows mounted, so you need to use live installer with gparted or a gparted ISO. You seem to have multiple "New Volumes", you know backup on same drive is barely a backup as when (not if) drive fails or user makes mistake all data could be erased. Better to have another drive.